# Run script and not lose access to prompt / terminal

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am running jmeter by launching the .sh script, once I do that I cannot start using the prompt again unless I ctrl-z, ctrl-c, or the script ends in some other way.  How can I launch that script and still be able to use the same console after the script is launched.  (i used to know how to do this, it's easy =()

I guess another way of putting it is how do I launch the script independently of the terminal.

Answer (score 6):

You can start your script in the background by putting `&` at the end of the command; something like

```
jmeter.sh &
```

If you want to avoid seeing any output, see [Silently start task in background](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50125/silently-start-task-in-background).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `screen` command. You can start a script or anything there, and then detach the "screen", and return to your original commandline. The command in the detached screen keeps running, even when you close the terminal or end your SSH session. You can go back to the screen anytime.

This is very useful when you login via SSH and your connection is slow, or you start a (remote) script that runs overnight and you don't want to keep your computer running all that time.

[**Screen Command Examples: Get Control of Linux / Unix Terminal**](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/screen-command-examples/)

Answer (score 1):

Stephen is right and the most simple as well as universal:

```
jmeter.sh &
```

But you might need more help working with jobs.  To learn more about putting jobs in the background and how to get back to them to the foreground, check out: https://www.thegeekdiary.com/understanding-the-job-control-commands-in-linux-bg-fg-and-ctrlz/

screen is a better choice in many situations as it is far more robust, but it is not always installed.  If screen is installed, then run

```
screen
jmeter.sh
```

then "detach the screen" with:

```
ctrl-a d
```

For more information, see: http://www.tecmint.com/screen-command-examples-to-manage-linux-terminals/