# Running multiple commands at the same time

Tags: shell, parallelism

I want to run two commands on terminal on my virtual machine at the same time.
I have this as of now:

```
sudo ptpd -c -g -b eth1 -h -D; sudo tcpdump -nni eth1 -e icmp[icmptype] == 8 -w capmasv6.pcap
```

However, the `tcpdump` command only starts running when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, and I don't want to cancel the first command.

If I just open two different terminals and write the command in each, is that fine or will it not work as I want it to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running each command in a different terminal will work; you can also start them in a single terminal with `&` at the end of the first to put it in the background (see [Run script and not lose access to prompt / terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189294/run-script-and-not-lose-access-to-prompt-terminal/189296#189296)):

```
sudo ptpd -c -g -b eth1 -h -D &
sudo tcpdump -nni eth1 -e icmp[icmptype] == 8 -w capmasv6.pcap
```